# How to set full page border in mpdf

Tags: mpdf

Is there a way to insert default page border to all the pages in the pdf?
There was any option found in mpdf. Any one help me ?

[image: View Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Create an image the same size as the paper stock you're using (A4, letter ect). Then set the image as a background on [`@page`](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html):

```
@page {
    background: url(<?= __DIR__ ?>/background.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-image-resize: 3;
}
```

Adjust the margins in `@page` so the text is displayed in-between your border.

Note: there's a bug in PDF.js that'll cause a blurry image to be displayed when using this method. It's fine when viewed in Adobe Reader though. If that's a problem, you can set an absolute-positioned Header or Footer and it'll do the same thing:

```
<style>
    @page {
        header: html_Header;
    }

    #background {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<htmlpageheader name="Header">
    <div id="background">
        <img src="<?= __DIR__ ?>/background.png" />
    </div>
</htmlpageheader>
```